# Linux/Unix variant for training system administrators

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, administration

Is there a Linux/Unix based operating system used for training sysadmins?

Some bugs would be deliberately included in the system and the training candidate is supposed to solve all of them. It should be something similar to [WebGoat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebGoat_Project).

Comment: There are a common set of tools targeted to sysadmins call Damn Vulnerable TOOL. Look for Damn Vulnerable Linux, like http://www.dvwa.co.uk/ (which is probably getting inspired from DVL for its naming.

Comment: It used to be called "Slackware" but I'm told that it's improved a great deal over the past two decades...

Comment: http://www.bsdcertification.org/resources/resources-for-bsd-certification

Answer (score 7):

To my knowledge, there is not a specific distro for this, but you might want to look at http://trouble-maker.sourceforge.net/ and make use of it on your favorite distro.

Comment: +1 Interesting! Do you happen to know if this is still in active development, though?

Comment: Currently I am using Arch Linux. I was not able to find support its support for Arch systems. @John anyway that was a helpful suggestion.

Comment: I don't know if it's still in active development, no - I just remember seeing it a year or two ago and thinking I liked the premise.

Comment: If you click on the "Download" link you go to the sourceforge page which has statistics, etc.  The last release was mid-2011.

Comment: @goldilocks Exactly. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 3):

there is a college professor that put together a good tutorial site called [linuxzoo.net](http://linuxzoo.net/) with assorted tutorials that will familiarize you with Unix/Linux basics, all the way up to beginning/intermediate administration topics...it's a great safe environment to start in where you don't have to worry about breaking anything.

Creating an account is free and its usage is also free.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this isn't much help to you; I'm including it here for its curio value only. It seems there *was* such a distro started by a German security lecturer who wanted to teach his students about vulnerabilities. I came across it by accident:

[Damn Vulnerable Linux](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=dvl)

Distrowatch (link above) says it's been discontinued, though and its [website](http://www.damnvulnerablelinux.org/) seems dead.